# Laravel eloquent use whereNotIn and Take in relationship data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

There is my code :

```
$course = Course::where('id', $activeCourseId)
        ->with(["blocks.cards" => function($q) use($cardsDueIds) {
            $q->whereNotIn('id', $cardsDueIds);
            $q->take(50);
        },
        "blocks.cards.contexts",
        "blocks.cards.user_contexts",
        "blocks.cards.block.course",
        "blocks.cards.thisUser"])
        ->first();
```

Course datas are like this :

```
{
  blocks: [
    0: {
      cards: [
       0: {id: 298736},
       1: {id: 293747}
      ]
    }
    1: {
      cards: [
       0: {id: 1234445}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I try to get the course with only 50 `blocks.cards` where `blocks.cards.id` are not in the `$cardsDueIds`.

Actually it does not work, with `take(50)` i get 0 cards and without `take(50)` i get all cards (but the whereNotIn doesnt work)...

Anyone know how to do this ? Thanks !

Comment: can you print $cardsDueIds is this array or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q->whereNotIn('id', $cardsDueIds)->take(50);
```

If doesn't work, Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097559/laravel-eloquent-limit-results-for-relationship).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry but cards is empty with your solution

Comment: Try `limit` instead of `take`.

Comment: Sorry, same result with ->limit(50)

Answer (score 0):

Please refrase your question (you say twice the same):

> Actually it does not work, with take(50) i get 0 cards and with take(50) i get all cards...