# Laravel Eloquent returns elements related to the first document only, when using with() + take() methods

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i'm trying to get user documents along with first three related meeting documents.

```
User::with(
    [
        'meetings' => function($query) {
            $query->take(3);
        }
    ]
)->get();
```

user-meeting relation in App\Models\User.php:

```
public function meetings(){
    return $this->hasMany(Meeting::class);
}
```

but as a result, i only get meetings related to the first user:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "63123a4906650000d2006de2",
    ...
    "meetings": [
      {
        "_id": "63123e0590530000860042bd",
        "user_id": "63123a4906650000d2006de2",
        "start_time": "2022-08-29T12:00:00.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-02T17:31:49.601000Z",
        "created_at": "2022-09-02T17:31:49.601000Z"
      },
      {
        "_id": "63123e0590530000860042be",
        "user_id": "63123a4906650000d2006de2",
        "start_time": "2022-08-29T12:15:00.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-02T17:31:49.602000Z",
        "created_at": "2022-09-02T17:31:49.602000Z"
      },
      {
        "_id": "63123e0590530000860042bf",
        "user_id": "63123a4906650000d2006de2",
        "start_time": "2022-08-29T12:30:00.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-02T17:31:49.603000Z",
        "created_at": "2022-09-02T17:31:49.603000Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "63123af290530000860042b2",
    ...
    "meetings": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "63123b0c90530000860042b5",
    ...
    "meetings": [
      
    ]
  }
]
```

without using take(), all the related meeting documents are loaded.

i'm using jenssegers-mongodb package for laravel-mongodb connection, but the issue also occurs on vanilla eloquent.

Comment: In conventional Eloquent relationships `with` performs an additional query and adding a `take` to that will affect that entire query. It may be a similar situation here.

Comment: update: that's not an issue with jenssegers-mongodb package, it also occurs on vanilla eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like @apokryfos [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73626685/laravel-eloquent-returns-elements-related-to-the-first-document-only-when-using#comment130016568_73626685), the `take()` eloquent method just adds 'limit' word at the end of the query. this type of query is more complex and isn't supported by vanilla eloquent.

fortunately, there is an additional package called [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit), which helps with this problem. in order to make it work, install that package by using `composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit` command and put `use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;` line inside both parent and children model classes.

sadly, mongodb isn't supported and there seem to be no efficient way to achieve this when using mongodb. some options that come to my mind are:

1. writing a query without the help of eloquent, using `DB::query()` for example,
2. [retrieving all records, displaying or mapping ones that are needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099548/5827880),
3. writing your own package :D